# How can I access another application's Isolated storage using my application

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to share some tokens/strings across my applications. How can we allow such sharing between applications by the same author?

Comment: Iif you made the other application or know the person who did and they can add some code to their app then you can pass it some XML/JSON with a call back URL to your app/response.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know that's impossible - I guess that's where "Isolated" comes in. However you can store whatever you like in cloud services like OneDrive. This also allows to sharing between devices.

Comment: Right - apps are [Sandboxed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402533(v=vs.105).aspx). With WP8.1 it is also possible to use `KnownFolders` and SD Card to share files of associated file types.

Answer (score 5):

The application model in WP 8.1 doesn't allow apps to reach into other apps isolated storage, but there are a few ways that you could use to move information between apps:

1. [Share Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh758314.aspx) - Launch the share picker and let the user choose to share the information. This runs the risk of the user not picking your app though.
2. [URI activation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh779670(v=win.10).aspx) - Choose a URI scheme to launch your apps. Again it is possible (but unlikely) that another app could intercept this, and you can only pass strings.
3. [Common File Location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776911(v=vs.85).aspx) - Store the file you want to share in the correct library, and then have the other app check for the shared file. Again the user can delete this file, or another app could read it.
4. Off Device Sharing - You can always share the information with a web service and then check it when the app launches.